# Can't see Swagger service endpoints

Tags: clojure, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to access my Swagger service endpoints. Here is the code:

```
(defn service-routes []
  ["/api"
   {:middleware [middleware/wrap-formats]
    :swagger {:id ::api}}
   ["" {:no-doc true}
    ["/swagger.json"
     {:get (swagger/create-swagger-handler)}]
    ["/swagger-ui*"
     {:get (swagger-ui/create-swagger-ui-handler
             {:url "api/swagger.json"})}]]
   ["/business-partners"
    {:get
     (fn [_]
       (response/ok (bp/business-partners-list)))}]
   ["/business-partner"
    {:post
     (fn [{:keys [params]}]
       (try
         (bp/save-business-partner params)
         (response/ok {:status :ok})
         (catch Exception e
           (let [{id :business-partners/error-id
                  errors :errors} (ex-data e)]
             (case id
               :validation
               (response/bad-request {:errors errors})
               (response/internal-server-error
                 {:errors {:server-error ["Failed to save message!"]}}))))))}]])
```

But when I tried to access http://localhost:3000/api/swagger.json in browser I got this response:

```
{"swagger":"2.0",
 "x-id":["businesspartners.routes.services/api"],
 "paths":{
   "/api/business-partners": {"get":  {}},
   "/api/business-partner":  {"post": {}}}}
```

I can't figure out why did I get this in json format and why not see Swagger UI to visaulize and interact with my services? I should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: the swagger.json route should indeed return meta-data like the above, not the ui. What happens if you visit '/api/index.html' ?

Answer (score 0):

I’d imagine you’ll find the swagger ui under /api

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue and using code generation with Java with language jaxrs
Once you generate the code you will see the index.html page generated with endpoints under target/generated-sources/swagger/ folder. Make sure you include it in you build and point api path to this page so that you can view endpoints as html.